# Can not open file with cyrillic path from window.open

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a path like `\\server\FILES\101-ПЦ\doc10.pdf`

```
var path = '\\server\FILES\101-ПЦ\doc10.pdf'
window.open(`file:${path}`, "_blank")
```

And trying to open a local file from window.open but have problem:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file://server/FILES/101-%D0%9D%D0%A6/doc10.pdf

What I should to do?

Comment: What protocol was used to load the page producing the error - "file://" or "http://" ? Basically you can't access client files from a page loaded from a server without user interaction.

Comment: if I enter manually "\\server\FILES\10-ПЦ\doc10.pdf" or "file:\\server\FILES\10-ПЦ\doc10.pdf" in browser url the document will be opened

Comment: So how can we [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you?

Comment: if I try to open the file from browser adress line everything OK but if I try window.open(`file:${path}`, "_blank") then have problem